why can't i import pandas in raspberrypi?
How to import pandas in raspberry pi? My code raises ImportError for Numpy even though all dependencies were installed:
import pandas as pd

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jinu/scale/hx711py/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python interpreter from there.


Does this answer your question? Error importing pandas on Raspberry Pi

Please indicate how you have tried to install pandas

This should work with the Raspberry Pi.
sudo apt install python-pandas

